# wamp no me deja ver mis páginas

Tags: wamp, localhost

buenas, mi problema es que Wamp no me permite abrir MIS proyectos, que es en donde visualizo las páginas que creo. Normalmente es ir a "disco local c" luego "wamp" luego a "www" y ahí pegar las carpetas con proyectos(páginas.php o htm). El problema es que ese procedimiento ya dicho, no me sirve, al hacerlo wamp solo me muestra mis proyectos pero en TEXTO, no como Links que me permitan visualizar mis páginas. Les dejo una imagen que muestra EXACTAMENTE mi problema.[imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWieI.png) Necesito ayuda urgente, por favor

Comment: Puedes acceder por `URL`  directamente: `localhost/tu-carpeta` `localhost/hola`

Comment: Gracias, no se me había ocurrido, que tonto jajaja, muchas gracias.

Comment: de nada, un placer ayudar.